# local variable and return value of function in windows batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

set /a n=99

echo before call test3
echo n=%n%

set ret=
call :test3 ret

echo after call test3
echo n=%n%

echo show array:
echo %ret.Array[0]%
echo %ret.Array[1]%
echo %ret.Array[2]%
echo %ret.Array[3]%

ECHO Press any key to close the windows...
pause>NUL
goto :eof

:test3
setlocal
set /a n=0

:Loop-Start
if %n% GEQ 3 goto :Loop-End

endlocal

set %~1.Array[%n%]=V%n%

setlocal

set /a n=n+1

goto :Loop-Start
:Loop-End

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Hi,

I have written a function test3 with local var named n, and test3 get a reference to variable named ret from caller as it parameter.

As I show in the code, I want my test3 to make an array has three elements, variable named ret in caller would hold the array.

But in caller when I print the array, I found I have not got three elements in the array.

who can help? thanks

Comment: While in the sub `:test3` n is set to 0, this is reset after the 1st endlocal after :Loop-Start. So the next command `set %~1.Array[%n%]=V%n%` has still n=99. You can see this if you replace the 4 `echo %ret.Array[...` with a `set ret.Array[` which returns `ret.Array[99]=V99`. So nothing extraordinary  just your misconception what happens.

Comment: @LotPings in function test3, I hope code: `set %~1.Array[%n%]=V%n%` becomes `set %~1.Array[0]=V0`, `set %~1.Array[1]=V1`, `set %~1.Array[2]=V2`, but result is not what I want. Once go beyond first `endlocal`, variable `n` get value of global variable `n` defined at caller of function `test3`

Comment: The **only** way to pass a value from a setlocal region is to put it on the same line as the endlocal => `endlocal & set %~1.Array[%n%]=V%n%` but that won't help as the loop is terminated because 99 geq 3 .

Comment: @LotPings Is it possible to set parameter to value of local variable not global variable has same name in windows batch? Is there some work around?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand parameter of what??? I explained your issue, if this refers to the current question [edit] the question to contain detail information - otherwise ask a new question.

Comment: @LotPings let variable `n` at `%~1.Array[%n%]=V%n%` only get its local variable value, not value of global variable who has same name as local variable

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Following is working code for subroutine test3:

```
:test3

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a n=0

for /l %%i in (0,1,3) do (
   set s1=V!n!

   if defined _ret (
      set _ret=!_ret! ^& 
   )
   set _ret=!_ret!set %~1.Array[!n!]=V!n!

   set /a n=n+1
)

(
   endlocal
   %_ret%
)
goto :eof
```

Thanks

Comment: `set _ret=!_ret! ^&` includes a trailing space to the set value. Perhaps you could instead use `set _ret=!_ret!^&` to omit the space.

Comment: @michael_heath Is `set v1=abc & set v2=def` same with `set v1=abc&set v2=def`?

Comment: The `&` will terminate the end of the set value. For the first `v1`, the value will be `abc ` and the 2nd `abc`. If you insert double quotes around the echoed items after `echo show array:` line, you may view `V0 `, `V1 `, `V2 ` and `V3` values between the quotes. Only the last value has no trialing space. To fix, omit the space before `^&`.

Comment: @michael_heath you are right, the value of v1 has a trailing space and value of v2 is `def` has no trailing space in code in my comments. Thanks.

Comment: @user2799433 Your batch file in question with your code for subroutine `test3` as posted in this answer produces exactly the same output as using for subroutine `test3` just two lines: `for /L %%i in (0,1,3) do set "%~1.Array[%%i]=V%%i"` and `goto :EOF`. You really make your task more complex than necessary by not using the loop variable, but using an environment variable `n` being incremented by one on each loop iteration like the loop variable referenced with delayed environment variable expansion which would not be needed at all on using the loop variable.

Comment: @Mofi this is a code for testing. In most case when developing, it is not only loop variable be used. when some complex logic and function involved, I can write more complex code based on this simple but important testing code, which should not be replaced by your two lines.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So the example code in question was not best for the coding issue you wanted to solve in real. Please note that your code creates a long command line with code in loop and there is the command line length limit of 8191 characters. And for execution of command line `%_ret%` it would be more safe __in general__ to use in loop `set _ret=!_ret!set "%~1.Array[!n!]=V!n!"`. And finally `set /a n=n+1` could be optimized to `set /a n+=1`.

Comment: @Mofi you are right. I won’t show my real code for coding issues in real here of course. I would shows critical part which represents my issues, this makes others easy to think. for some syntax, I need more time to improve, I have work in this for one week.